# Python list get unique element based on text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very bad unformatted list **["'Foo'", 'Foo', 'Bar']**

What I want is the unique element from the list based on the Text.

```
input_list = ["'Foo'", 'Foo', 'Bar']

Output list = ['Foo', 'Bar']


>>> ls = ["'Foo'", 'Foo', 'Bar']
>>> ls = list(set(ls))
>>> ls
['Foo', 'Bar', "'Foo'"]
>>>
```

Comment: what does "based on text" mean? remove punctuation from the elements?

Comment: yes we can say that remove punctuation or any other symbols

Comment: Your code is right, except you have 2 sets of quotes on the first "Foo".

Comment: yes but the issue is punctuation's

Comment: "any other symbol" is still ambiguous. That would include also the ASCII letters. At least them I guess you want to keep :)

Comment: can we keep only alphabets and trim all symbols ??

Comment: The one answer does trim all symbols given in your input.  Don't expand your question, especially as this expansion requires you to make a better attempt to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import string

def clean(item):
    return ''.join(char for char in item if char in string.ascii_letters)

ls = ["'Foo'", 'Foo', 'Bar']
ls = list(set(clean(item) for item in ls))
print(ls)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't keep the order

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal the OP does not specify they want to preserve the order. Their own attempt at solving it is using `set`.

Comment: Yes, but please look at the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @[buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran)'s answer but uses [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain the order.

Code:

```py
import string
from collections import OrderedDict

def clean(item):
    return ''.join(char for char in item if char in string.ascii_letters)

ls = ["'Foo'", 'Foo', 'Bar']
ls = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(clean(item) for item in ls))
print(ls)
```

Comment: in 3.7+ no need to use `OrderedDict`, regular `dict` will preserve the order of insertion.

Comment: @buran Just put if if the version is less then 3.7